# Change CSS properties of the element which doesn't exists yet

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to style the elements which are created after the form submission. The form itself is created by the JS script and I don't have access to it.
I already managed to get it working using `setInterval`

Is there some better solution?

```
setInterval(function () {
  if (document.querySelector('.submitted-message')) {
    document.querySelector('.submitted-message').style.cssText = "display: flex; font-size: 20px"
  }
}, 100);
```

Comment: There is absolutely no problem with this. It is clearly readable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Create a CSS class that is loaded by default:

```
.someClass{
    color:red;
}
```

and when you create your new elements, make sure that their class attribute contains `someClass`.

EDIT It looks like the elements already have a class of `submitted-message`, so just create a CSS rule to target that class:

```
.submitted-message{
    display: flex; 
    font-size: 20px
}
```

right?